# Can i add password field into my wp registration form?

Tags: users, forms, user-registration, password

I would like to users can choose their own password on registration form and disable sending generated password email to them.
Here it is my custom registration code:

```
<form id="register-form" class="wp-user-form" action="<?php echo site_url('wp-login.php?action=register', 'login_post') ?>" method="post" role="form" style="display: none;">
  <div class="g-login-div">
    <a href="#" class="g-login-link">ثبت نام با حساب گوگل <i class="g-login-icon"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-divider">
    <hr><span class="or-text">یا</span><hr>
  </div>
  <label class="panel-body-label"> فرم ثبت نام را پر کنید:</label>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="user_login">نام کاربری</label>
    <input type="text" name="user_login" id="user_login" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="نام کاربری" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($user_login)); ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="user_email">ایمیل شما</label>
    <input type="text" name="user_email" id="user_email" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="ایمیل شما" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($user_email)); ?>">
  </div>
  <?php do_action('register_form'); ?>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="user_pass">رمز عبور</label>
    <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="رمز عبور" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <input type="submit" name="user-submit" id="register-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-register user-submit" value="ثبت نام">
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>?register=true" />
        <input type="hidden" name="user-cookie" value="1" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Username and name created correctly in DB but not password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these instructions:
[Allow Users to Set Password During Registration](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/258525/allow-users-to-set-password-during-registration)

Comment: Thanks. can you integrate this hooks to my custom form? or explain how to use them?

Comment: Please ofcourse